# Unable to read database header in SQLITE3

Tags: sqlite

I installed SQLITE3 on my Ubuntu VM running on WSL2 in Windows 11.

I created a sample database with one table and few records.

When I run the command `.dbinfo ?DB?` I get the below error msg:

> unable to read database header

Please advice on how to resolve the issue... Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I turned the header ON and it works. I ran the command as "`.header ON`"

Answer (score 1):

Try `.dbinfo` (without an argument). The argument would be used to get the status information about any attached database(s).

Comment: I reinstalled sqlite3 on CentOS Stream 9 and ran the command sqlite3 testdb. After which I ran .dbinfo and still getting the same error.

Comment: Assuming file `testdb` was created by command `sqlite3 testdb` that would be the expected result for a 0-length file.

Comment: I turned the header ON and it works. I ran the command as ".header ON"